# How do I bundle npm Halfmoon's JS with existing code via Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, halfmoon

So, I want to use the Halfmoon framework in a personal project and I have it downloaded via npm. In order to use the Javascript it shows as an example (in this page https://www.gethalfmoon.com/docs/download/#using-npm) to import the library with a require statement.

```
var halfmoon = require("halfmoon");
halfmoon.onDOMContentLoaded();
```

I was hoping to bundle this code with any future Javascript files into one large `scripts.js` file, but require statements do not work in browsers.

Browserify seemed like a good option, but there is no up-to-date plugin for gulp. Ran into similar issues with Rollup where the gulp plugin was problematic.

My hope was to have a gulp function structured like this:

```
function bundle() {
    
    return gulp.src('./src/js/main.js')
        .pipe(theFunctionThatMakesItWork())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/js'));
}
```

I am not completely attached to doing this in gulp but that would be my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this will work, but you could probably try downloading the `halfmoon.js` file on Github. It is different from the one in npm, mainly that it is meant to run using the `<script>` tag, and doesn't need the `require` statement.

Link to the file on Github: https://github.com/halfmoonui/halfmoon/blob/master/js/halfmoon.js

Edit: Also, on this file, the `halfmoonOnDOMContentLoaded()` is run automatically when the DOM is loaded.